# Unsafe C# - Instantiate Pointer at lowest memory address and overwrite

Tags: c#, .net, pointers, unsafe

Is it possible to instantiate a pointer using (unsafe) C# at any given memory address (which one would be the lowest?) and simply start overwriting the memory with continuous random data until a PC crashes?

Could someone provide me with an example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Until the PC crashes? No. Until *your process* crashes, then yes. But if you just want your process to crash, there's much easier ways of doing that then just overwriting random memory locations...

Windows uses a technique called [virtual memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory) to make sure that any memory that you can access in process "A" cannot affect the memory that's being used by process "B" (unless you use explicit mechanisms to *share* memory). So one process cannot (normally) affect the memory in another.

Comment: Very good answer, since it goes straight to the point. If I may add, you can't do that with C# nor with any language (unless you use some specific method or API). Pointers are always restricted to the process address space.